# Restkit 0.20 Dynamic Nested Mapping

Tags: restkit-0.20

I am using Restkit 0.20 to map and store objects in core data. For basic mappings it works well, but it doesnt work for nested dynamic mappings. This is my example response:

```
[
    {
        "actor": {
            "id": 7,
            "first_name": "Murat",
            "last_name": "Akbal"
        },
        "target": {
            "content_type": "dress",
            "type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "leggings",
                "kind": "bottom"
            },
            "style": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "sport"
            },
            "full_name": "Murat - sport leggings",
            "id": 19,
        }
    }, 
    {
        "actor": {
            "id": 7,
            "first_name": "Murat",
            "last_name": "Akbal"
        },
        "target": {
            "content_type": "wardrobe",
            "style": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "sport"
            },
            "id": 38,
            "season": "spring",
            "name": "asdasd"
        }
    }
]
```

I use following entity mapping to map response:

```
//create entity mapping
RKEntityMapping *objectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Action"
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

//create dynamic mapping
RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];    

//dressMapping and wardrobeMapping predefined mappings, they work well when mapping the wardobe and dress alone.
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    if ([[representation valueForKey:@"content_type"] isEqualToString:@"wardrobe"]) {
       return wardrobeMapping;
    } else if ([[representation valueForKey:@"content_type"] isEqualToString:@"dress"]) {
       return dressMapping;
    }
    return nil;
}];


[objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"target" toKeyPath:@"target" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];

//maps actor
[objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"actor" toKeyPath:@"actor" withMapping:actorMapping]];
```

And lastly, I register the objectMapping as response descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

This doesn't work for my example response, gives the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Wardrobe 0x110e1a90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Wardrobe is not key value coding-compliant for the key "type".'
```

It asks "type" key which does not exist in wardrobe, but exists for dress. Somehow, it tries to map wardrobe with dress mapping. Do you have any idea about that issue?

fyi, type of target in coredata is transformable.

Comment: Can you show the wardrobe and dress mappings. Also, have you turned on trace logging for the mapping: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Actually it mapped response successfully, but when deleteLocalObjectsMissingFromMappingResult is preforming it throws an exception from this line:

```
id managedObjects = event.keyPath ? [objectsAtRoot valueForKeyPath:event.keyPath] : objectsAtRoot;
```

it seeks keyPath for all object at mapping results instead of each individual object. So in my situation it cannot find the "type" key for wardrobe because it does not exist. As a basic solution, I surrounded the code block with try-catch